# How debug and use grabAttributeFrom in codeceptjs?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, functional-testing, codeceptjs

In my case all identifiers in a page is generated dynamically. So I can't use xpath.

I've found method in the documentation: `grabAttributeFrom`.

- How I can see what's inside, when I using cmd in --debug mode?
- Can I use grabAttributeFrom for extracting xpath's from a page when I searching inputs?
- How I can get access to inputs which have name and they xpath generates dynamically and I can't use xpath's?

I tried this code:

```
I.fillField(locate('input').inside('.jq-panel-body-default').at(2),'John');
```

but it doesn't work correct and generate exception:

```
 FAIL  Field "{"type":"xpath","output":null,"strict":true,"locator":{"xpath":".//input[ancestor::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(./@class), ' '), ' jq-panel-body-default ')]][position()=2]"},"value":".//input[ancestor::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(./@class), ' '), ' jq-panel-body-default ')]][position()=2]"}" was not found by text|CSS|XPath
```

Comment: You got many questions my friend. Let's clean up the question a bit.

Comment: Even with formatting a bit, the questions will take few more tried to clean up properly.

Answer (score 1):

1. How I can see what's inside, when I using cmd in --debug mode?

Inside.. what?
If you want to log value of attribute, grab it and log:

```
Scenario("test", async (I) => {
  ...
  const attributeValue = await I.grabAttributeFrom(<locator>, <attribute>);
  console.log(attributeValue);
  ...
});
```

2. Can I use grabAttributeFrom for extracting xpath's from a page when I searching inputs?

`grabAttributeFrom` is for grabbing of attributes value, not for xpath finding.
But if you ask, can you use xpath in locator argument, yes you can.

3. How I can get access to inputs which have name and they xpath generates dynamically and I can't use xpath's?

This is not enough to ask you. Share some DOM part or something to understand.
If you mean `name` attribute, you can use filtering by name: `//input[@name="<your element name>"]`